# Python and/or Perl VS bash

Tags: python, perl, bash, admin

I normally code admin scripts in Python and I know of many that code them in Perl. I was about to invest some time on improving my skills on bash programming. But I wonder if people around think that this is a good idea ?

I know bash is a good skill to have and market very often demand it but ... if I can get by with Python or Perl then ... is it really worth the effort ?

As answers I am looking for cases where actually bash is way better than Perl or Python to develop admin scripts.

Comment: perl/python and bash use two very different philosophies, bash tries to leverage other programs to the largest possible extent (typing 'x', will execute program 'x') , something which neither perl nor python does. I say it's worth learning, regardless of whether you want too use it or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything you learn can only benefit you, *never* is it a bad idea to learn something. That said, if you feel you're productive with Python then I don't see why you would need bash. Python is more powerful (being a full blown programming language) and IMO has a nicer, more readable syntax. Bash *is* often useful for quick and dirty scripting, though.

If you do decide to learn it, here are some resources to get you started:

1. [A Bash guide for beginners](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
2. [The magnificent Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ)
3. [Common Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Although some rules-of-thumb are occasionally thrown in the air regarding when you should use each, I think you'll figure it out once you get to know all of your options. Having another tool in your arsenal is always an advantage.

Comment: I would like to add that if you use the command line occasionally (or more than that) knowing bash is an advantage, as everything you can type in a script you can also type on the command line.

Comment: The most useful trick I know for bash is X="${X%00}"  which strips '00'  from 'X'  =)

Comment: @KentFredric: to be exact it strips the 1st '00' occurence from the back of the X string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if this is only your machine and you're not supposed to share those administration scripts with any other one, so you'd better to keep doing that in Python (which seems you feel more comfortable on that).

But if you have colleagues or your admin scripts are supposed to employee by other people, so let keep it in a way that is more popular and more understandable for others also: Bash!

Also I guess if you know Bash, you can simply use dozens of existing Bash scripts by customizing them or improving them to whatever which is more suitable for you!